# associate values from different lists python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I need to display the months that with 10% lower rainfall would have been below the drought level. For that, I created two different lists:

```
months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
rainValues = []
```

I just copied this piece of code to understand how the values are stored:

```
enterRain = float(input("Please enter a number in the range 0 to 300"))
rainValues.append(enterRain)
```

I want to associate the month for each value when the user inputs and displays properly the result. I used this code:

```
NearDroughtMonths = []
LowerDroughtMonths = []
for i in range(len(rainValues)):
   percentage = rainValues[i] * 0.8
   NearDroughtMonths.append(percentage)
   for i in range(len(rainValues),len(months)):
      if NearDroughtMonths[i] < enterDroughtValue :
         LowerDroughtMonths.append(months[i])

   if len(LowerDroughtMonths) != 0:
      for n in range(len(LowerDroughtMonths)):
         print("The months when the rainfall was below the drought level are",LowerDroughtMonths[n],end=",")
   elif len(LowerDroughtMonths) == 0:
     print("There aren't months when the rainfall was 20% below the drought level")
```

The code doesn't give errors, the problem is .. it doesn't print properly the months because I think this isn't associating the `month[x]` with `rainValue[x]`..

Comment: To make it easy for others to understand your problem, please post the shortened but working version of your entire program, like this: http://sscce.org/ Please also specify the input you give to the program, and the output you get, and the output you expect.

Comment: What range of values do you expect `for i in range(len(rainValues),len(months)):` to cover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want something like this (I have made up some input for rainfall and drought_level). You need to use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) to associate the months with the rainfall levels.

```
months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
monthly_rainfall = [100, 200, 20, 280, 50, 270, 200, 90, 80, 110, 130, 140]
drought_level = 100
drought_months = []
for month, rainfall in zip(months, monthly_rainfall):
    if rainfall < drought_level * .8:
        drought_months.append(month)    
if drought_months:
    print ("The months when the rainfall was below the drought level are", ', '.join(drought_months))
else:
    print ("There aren't months when the rainfall was 20% below the drought level")
```

Your code doesn't work for several reasons - the indentation seems wrong (perhaps you pasted it wrongly here?), you define two nested loops both using `i` as a variable, and you try to iterate over `range(len(rainValues),len(months))` which is probably an empty list.

Also you say you are looking for months that with 10% less rainfall would be below the drought level but in your code you mention months when rainfall was 20% below the drought level. I have kept the latter.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm having a little trouble working out exactly what you want from the way your code/question are structured right now. That said, because you're using the corresponding `i` as an index into the NearDroughtMonths list, I suspect this:

```
range(len(rainValues),len(months))
```

Should be this:

```
range(len(NearDroughtMonths))
```

Edit: Stuart's answer points out that you're using `i` twice inside nested loops as well, which is right on the mark and certainly could cause you problems.